# Jupyter Notebook does not work fully in Pycharm

Tags: python, ipython, pycharm, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I am following [these](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PYH/Using+IPython+Notebook+with+PyCharm) steps to run IPython in the Pycharm IDE. On pressing `run` button in any cell, I do get below pop-up window

[image]

According to the mentioned guide (given link), On pressing `OK`, I should get following message

[image]

But, I am not getting any type of message/response. So, I am not able to see the output of any cell contents. Does anyone know why I am not getting any response on selecting `OK`?

System Information:

```
OS: MAC OS 10.10.3
 Python: 2.7.10 using Anaconda 2.3.0
 Ipython: 4.0.0
 Pycharm: pycharm community addition 2016.2
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved following:

First I followed the reply to the [issue jupyter-notebook No such file or directory: 'conda'](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/921), in short you should do:

```
conda update nb_conda nb_conda_kernels nb_anacondacloud
```

Then, I ran my jupyter notebook in my browser. I took note where the Jupyter notebook was running, i.e.

```
The Jupyter Notebook is running at: http://localhost:8888/
```

Then I started a new Jupyter Notebook in PyCharm2016.2.2, and when it asked about the Jupyter Notebook URL I changed the default `http://127.0.0.1:8888`  to `http://localhost:8888/`

and finally it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For the PyCharm Jupyter notebooks, to see results you need to open up a jupyter notebook.

The reason why you don't just do all your code in Jupyter Notebooks is because Pycharm helps with LaTex integration and many more functions.

Comment: I have already opened a Notebook (created using Browser)  in Pycharm, but I am not getting execution results.

Answer (score 0):

According to this answer:

[Jupyter notebook server not working with latest PyCharm 2017.2 update. How do I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45370229/jupyter-notebook-server-not-working-with-latest-pycharm-2017-2-update-how-do-i)

You need a package named ”notebook“. I had the same issue and I solved it by installing the package.